# I can create open API 2 documenttaion(via swagger) but I can not create open API 3 documenttaion

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am trying to create API documentation. I am doing this using Swagger. I Added these dependencies:

```
 <!-- swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that, I created simple documentation:

```
private static Swagger getSwagger(List<Route> routes) {
        Swagger swagger = new Swagger();
        swagger.basePath("localhost:4567");
        swagger.info(new Info().description("My API")
                .version("V1.0")
                .title("API documentation")
                .contact(new Contact().name("Name").url("site.com")));
        swagger.schemes(Arrays.asList(Scheme.HTTP, Scheme.HTTPS));
        swagger.consumes("application/json");
        swagger.produces("application/json");
        swagger.tag(new Tag().name("API"));

        Reader reader = new Reader(swagger);

        for (Route route : routes) {
            reader.read(route.getClass());
        }

        return reader.getSwagger();
    }
```

and converted this object to JSON String:

```
public static String swaggerToJson(Swagger swagger) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(swagger);
    }
```

It works fine. But I got this field in generated documentation: `swagger: '2.0'`

When I insert my JSON to swagger UI I get errors like:

```
Structural error at paths./api/users.get.responses.200
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: responseSchema
Jump to line 26
```

It happens because my code generates open API 2.0 documentation. But swagger UI expects open API 3.0. I can convert it in the swagger UI:

[image]

But I want to create open API 3.0 documentation. How can I do it?

Comment: it sounds like [Helen's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013998/421195) is spot-on: all you need to do is update your libraries from 1.6.2 to 2.xxx (e.g. 2.1.6) and rebuild.  Please be sure to "Upvote" her response if it was helpful, and "Accept" if it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To generate an OpenAPI 3.0 document, update `io.swagger` libraries to v. **2.x** (2.1.6 as of the time of writing). You'll probably also need to make some changes in your code and annotations because there are breaking changes in `io.swagger.*` 2.x compared to 1.x.

- [Swagger Core 2.X Getting started](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started)
- [Swagger Core 2.X Annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations)